# Configurable Product Swatches price Version 1.9.2.2

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, configurable-product, configuration, custom-options

I'm using Magento version 1.9.2.2, its working fine but custom option/configurable product price not updating.
[image]

Comment: did you get your aswer??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your console for js errors, the price change happens by js added in product view page. Maybe it stopped working due to js conflict, If there is no error on browser console then first check the same by disabling the module, if starts working then you need to work on js added by module.

Try to call `optionsPrice.reload();` function on change event whenever you want to reload the price. This might help you.

Comment: Thanks for replying me, but I'm new one to Magento so I'm little bit confused about your answer